# Erro no argumento map

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou com dificuldades para entender essa parte ando fazendo aulas de flutter e me deparei com esse erro onde fala que estou passando um map Dynamic,Dynamic para um String, Object já tive um problema semelhante com o list e a solução era add o tipo no future, mas essa tecnica não funciona para map
segue o codigo:

import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

const String contactTable = "contactTable";
const String idColumn = "idColumn";
const String nameColumn = "nameColumn";
const String emailColumn = "emailColumn";
const String phoneColumn = "phoneColumn";
const String imgColumn = "imgColumn";

class ContactHelper {

static final ContactHelper _instance = ContactHelper.internal();

factory ContactHelper() => _instance;

ContactHelper.internal();

late Database _db;

Future get db async {
if(_db != null){
return _db;
} else {
_db = await initDb();
return _db;
}
}

Future initDb() async {
final databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
final path = join(databasesPath, "contactsnew.db");

```
return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: (Database db, int newerVersion) async {
  await db.execute(
      "CREATE TABLE $contactTable($idColumn INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $nameColumn TEXT, $emailColumn TEXT,"
          "$phoneColumn TEXT, $imgColumn TEXT)"
  );
});
```

}

Future saveContact(Contact contact) async {
Database dbContact = await db;
contact.id = await dbContact.insert(contactTable, contact.toMap());
return contact;
}

Future<Contact?> getContact(int id) async {
Database dbContact = await db;
List maps = await dbContact.query(contactTable,
columns: [idColumn, nameColumn, emailColumn, phoneColumn, imgColumn],
where: "$idColumn = ?",
whereArgs: [id]);
if(maps.isNotEmpty){
return Contact.fromMap(maps.first);
} else {
return null;
}
}

Future deleteContact(int id) async {
Database dbContact = await db;
return await dbContact.delete(contactTable, where: "$idColumn = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
}
// solução encontrada aqui para tipo de lista não funciona em coisas do tipo map
// aparentimente aqui é outro caminho para se fazer no final a mesma coisa
Future updateContact(Contact contact) async {
Database dbContact = await db;
return await dbContact.update(contactTable,
contact.toMap(),
where: "$idColumn = ?",
whereArgs: [contact.id]);
}
//erro corrigido solução agora na nova versão do flutter é preciso especificar de novo to tipo da lista dentro do future
// só assim finciona
Future<List> getAllContacts() async {
Database dbContact = await db;
List listMap = await dbContact.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM $contactTable");
List listContact = [];
for(Map m in listMap){
listContact.add(Contact.fromMap(m));
}
return listContact;
}

Future<int?> getNumber() async {
Database dbContact = await db;
return Sqflite.firstIntValue(await dbContact.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $contactTable"));
}

Future close() async {
Database dbContact = await db;
dbContact.close();
}

}

class Contact {

late int id;
late String name;
late String email;
late String phone;
late String img;

Contact();

Contact.fromMap(Map map){
id = map[idColumn];
name = map[nameColumn];
email = map[emailColumn];
phone = map[phoneColumn];
img = map[imgColumn];
}

Map toMap() {
Map<String, dynamic> map = {
nameColumn: name,
emailColumn: email,
phoneColumn: phone,
imgColumn: img
};
if(id != null){
map[idColumn] = id;
}
return map;
}

@override
String toString() {
return "Contact(id: $id, name: $name, email: $email, phone: $phone, img: $img)";
}

}

Comment: Boas-vindas ao site. É importante **[edit] e adicionar um [mcve] (NÃO delete e NÃO repita a pergunta)** ([NÃO use imagens para mostrar códigos e logs](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/3635)), com um passo a passo do que já fez e explicar de forma clara e objetiva e então aguarde o processo de reabertura (que será avaliado por outros usuários). Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Obrigado por compreender.